# How do you check is a char input is longer than one letter, without having it be an array in C++?

Tags: c++, char

I need to get a `std::cin` input from the user with a char *not* declared as an array, How can I check if that input is longer that one character? So I am making a hangman game, everything works fine, except I haven't figured out how to check this. I have tried just putting in an array locations and using the `char.at()` function. Are there any other ways? This is sort of what it would look like.

```
#include all the packages nessecary
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    while word has not been guessed {
        char guess;
        cin >> guess;
        if (guess is longer than one letter) {
            cout << "That is longer than one letter";
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

That is just a pseudo code example though.

Comment: Why use a single `char`? Read the whole line into an `std::string`, then analyze the string to make sure it only contains a single character, while possibly ignoring spaces.

Comment: There is also [std::basic_istream::peek](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek)

Comment: Since it is a hangman game, I need to check if the input is inside a string using `.find(char)`, which only takes a char as a parameter.

Comment: [This](https://repl.it/@redsox2/Hangman#main.cpp) is the repl.it if you want to see the full  code. If you enter multiple characters, it chechs them all, how can I make it not do that?

Answer (score 0):

A `char` is only a single character. You could peek what is left in the stream after extracting that single character, but perhaps simpler is to read a full string (which basically is a character array).

```
std::string x;
while (x.size() != 1) {
    std::cout << "please enter one character";
    std::cin >> x;
}
```